my income is halal or haram
my name is Talha, and I work for an affiliate network.My role is affiliate manager, and I find affiliates to promote our offers. We have offers in home improvement, solar, and loans. When the affiliate generates leads, I also get commission from it. Is it halal for me to get commission from loan leads, as my company is not providing the loan directly to customers; they just send leads to buyers, and then they provide loans? Is my earning halal?

Assalamoalikum Talha. Welcome to Islam SE. Your question is rather specific and can better be answered by taking a direct fatwa from a scholar. You may ask this on sites like seekersguidance.org, islamqa.info, askimam.org, islamweb.com, or another site based on your denomination of Islam. A few general answers I found online for this since you have asked: https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa/7919/fiqh-of-charging-commissions/ https://islamqa.info/en/answers/21980/is-commission-prohibited-in-islam .

For more info on how to ask on Islam SE, please view: https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . Always make sure that your questions are not extra specific to your scenario, so that they are answerable with one straightforward answer with the right references and don't warrant a fatwa. Moreover, make sure that your questions are also not too open-ended and opinion-based so that it doesn't gather debateful, and often, baseless answers. Be concise and ask one laser-pointed question per post. Jazak Allah khayr.
